# JS: While loop to find the product of consecutive integers

Tags: javascript, loops, while-loop

all!

I'm new to programming and trying to write a while loop that will return the product of all numbers 1 to n, inclusive. I can't get my code to work properly; it keeps returning weird numbers.

I think the problem is with the first line of the while loop. It's like it's not multiplying, but I don't know why.

Here is the code I wrote:

```
var n = 7;
var multiplier = 1;

while (multiplier <= n){
    multiplier = (multiplier * multiplier+1);

    if (n < 6){
        multiplier+= 2;
    }
    else {
        multiplier++;
    };
};

console.log(multiplier);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your use of the `multiplier` variable, you are using it to store the result, instead you need to use a separate variable to store the result and use it as a counter variable like

```js
var n = 5;
var multiplier = 1;


var result = 1;
while (multiplier <= n) {
  result *= multiplier++;

};

document.body.innerHTML = (result);
```

---

If you look at your loop below, at the end of 1st iteration multiplier is 3, end of second loop it is 11 which is higher than 7 so the loop exists.

```js
var n = 7;
var multiplier = 1;


while (multiplier <= n) {
  multiplier = (multiplier * multiplier + 1);

  if (n < 6) {
    multiplier += 2;
  } else {
    multiplier++;
  };
  snippet.log('loop: ' + multiplier)
};

snippet.log('result: ' + multiplier);
```

```html
<!-- To show result in the dom instead of console, only to be used in the snippet not in production -->
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Thank you so much! I really appreciate it.